# Query searching for value less than X is returning nothing

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have a collection, where I save accessTokens and their expiration time.
I want to automatically load all the ones that are expiring within the next X days.

I have already confirmed that the Database and collection does contain an entry, that it should return. I have done this by simply setting an empty query to return everything that is in the collection.

```
// HighestExptime is the timestamp of the latest day that I want to select
query := bson.M{"expiration": bson.M{"$lte": highestExpTime}}

// dbo is just an instance of a *mongo.Database struct
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30 * time.Second)
cur, err := dbo.Collection(dbLogin.DBCollection).Find(ctx, query)
```

The Documents look like this:

```
{
  userID // string
  accessToken // string
  refreshToken // string
  expiration // int
}
```

I would expect it to return every entry where the `expiration` is lower than the `highestExpTime` and is therefore "older" in that sense.

But when I actually execute it, it just returns an empty response and no error.

Comment: Please show how you execute the query and how the documents in your DB look like. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: @icza i edited the question to show the execution of the query as well, but i dont think thats the problem as other queries work with it

Comment: And what is `highestExpTime` in your Go code?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem myself.
Turns out that my other NodeJS process added the Document only with Strings, which is the reason why `$lte` returned nothing.

I just had to make sure everything related to this is added as an integer/float.